# $G$ is cyclic iff $f(H) = H$ for every automorphism $f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a finite group, $|G| = n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2$ such that $n$ is not divisible with the cube of any prime number.
>
> Prove that $G$ is cyclic $\iff$ $\forall f \in Aut(G), f(H) = H$, for every subgroup $H$ of $G$.

For the direct implication, I tried assuming the contrary and then try to use the fact that $G = <x>$, but I couldn't solve the problem.

For the inverse implication, using the inner automorphisms, we get that every subgroup $H$ of $G$ is normal. But I don't know how to use the fact that $n$ is not divisible with the cube of any prime number in order to prove that $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: The fact that every subgroup of $G$ is normal does not imply that $G$ is commutative.

Comment: What has that got to do with it? Every subgroup of the quaternion group $Q_8$ is normal, but $Q_8$ is not commutative.

Comment: @DerekHolt It does imply that the group is abelian in this case, since the order is not divisible by any cube. But it is not very clear that this is something the OP is expected to know.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't think it is something I am expected to know (I am still in secondary school)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes I realise that, but the OP was clearly under the impression that every subgroup normal implied commutativity, and I wanted to correct that!

Comment: Do you know how to use that for all primes $p$ the Sylow $p$-subgroups are normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be the following:

"$\Rightarrow$": If $G=\langle x\rangle$ is cyclic of order $n$, it has only one subgroup of order $m$ for every $m\vert n$ (the one generated by $x^{n/m}$). As $\lvert f(H)\rvert =\lvert H\rvert$ for any automorphism $f$, this implies $f(H)=H$ for any $f\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and any subgroup $H\subset G$.

"$\Leftarrow$": Now assume that $f(H)=H$ for any $f\in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and any subgroup $H\subset G$. As pointed out by you and in the comments, applying this to the inner automorphisms implies that $G$ is abelian(*). Then, the sturcture theorem on finitely generated abelian groups states that 
$$G\simeq \prod_iG_i,$$
where $G_{i}$ is a $p_i$-group, for pairwise distinct primes $p_i$ (more precisely, it states that the $G_{p_i}$ are direct products of some $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^k}:=\mathbb{Z}/p_i^k\mathbb{Z}$).
In particular, $\mathrm{Aut}(G)=\prod_i\mathrm{Aut}(G_i)$, as the $G_i$ are of coprime orders, so any $f\in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ must map $G_i$ on $G_i$.
By hypothesis (that no cube of a prime divides $\lvert G\rvert =n$), the $G_i$ must be of the form

1. $G_i\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$, or
2. $G_i\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{p_i^2}$, or
3. $G_i\simeq\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$.

Now, if any of the $G_i$ had form 3., say $G_{i_0}=\mathbb{Z}_{p_{i_0}}\times \mathbb{Z}_{p_{i_0}}=:H_1\times H_2$ for some $i_0$, consider $f:=\prod_i\varphi_i\in\prod_i\mathrm{Aut}(G_i)=\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, where $\varphi_i=\mathrm{Id}_{G_i}$ for any $i\neq i_0$ and $\varphi_{i_0}\in\mathrm{Aut}(G_{i_0})$ is the automorphism switching the two factors $H_1$ and $H_2$ of $G_{i_0}$. Then by construction $f(H_1)=H_2\neq H_1$, contradicting the assumption. So all $G_i$ are of the form 1. or 2., in particular cyclic, so $G$ is cyclic as a direct product of cyclic groups of coprime orders.

(*)  Considering the comments, I feel I should add a few words to this point, for completeness: Assuming $f(H)=H$ for any $f\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and any subgroup $H\subset G$, we want to show that $G$ is ablian, where we know that no cube of a prime divides $G$. As you pointed out, using the assumption for inner automorphisms, it follows that every subgroup of $G$ is normal. Let $p_i$, $i=1,\ldots,r$ be all (distinct) primes dividing $n=\lvert G\rvert$. Let $S_{p_i}$ be the (unique, as they are normal) $p_i$-Sylowsubgroups of $G$. By definition of Sylow-subgroups, $\lvert G\rvert = \prod_i\lvert S_{p_i}\rvert $ and the orders of the $S_{p_i}$ are coprime, in particular, 
$$\tag{1}S_{p_i}\cap S_{p_j}=\{1\}\text{ for }i\neq j.$$ 
As all $S_{p_i}$ are normal, we may build the subgroup $U:=S_{p_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot S_{p_r}\subset G$. By (1), we have an isomorphism 
$$\begin{aligned}
S_{p_1}\times\ldots \times S_{p_r}&\longrightarrow U\\ 
(s_1,\ldots,s_r)&\longmapsto s_1\cdot\ldots\cdot s_r.
\end{aligned}$$
In particular, $U$ is abelian, as $S_{p_i}$ is abelian for any $i$ (because $\lvert S_{p_i}\rvert =p_i^{k_i}$ for some $k_i$ by definition of a $p_i$-Sylowgroup and $k<3$ by the hypothesis that no cube of a prime divides $\lvert G\rvert $, so $S_{p_i}$ is abelian for all $i$ as a group of order either $p_i^2$ or $p_i$), and $\lvert U\rvert =\prod\lvert S_{p_i}\rvert =\lvert G\rvert $, so $U=G$.

Comment: Very nice proof!